# How to sample per key in a PCollection using different sampling rates per key?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am going through and switching a few Spark jobs over to Cloud Dataflow/Apache Beam 2.0.

One of these jobs uses `pairRdd.sampleByKey(sampleRates)` where `sampleRates` is a map where they key will match a key in the `pairRdd` and the value is the rate at which that key should be sampled.

I've found that Beam has a `Sample.fixedSizePerKey(sampleCount)` which seems to be the closest equivalent. However, that samples at a fixed amount (as the method name implies), but does so for every key.

I've dug into the `Sample` class a bit to see if it can be modified to accept a map and get a different count per key, but I can't find a way to access the key inside the `PCollection<KV<K,V>`.

How can I access the key inside the `PCollection` in the `PTransform` in order to do this?

Comment: The key of a KV<K, V> is available via .getKey(). Not sure what you mean by "accessing" the key?

Comment: It is.  However, there is some limitation.  The map of key to sampleRate/sampleCount is a `PCollectionView<MutableMap>` that must be accessed as a side input to the transform.  I don't know how else to say it other than, I don't understand conceptually how to combine the two, especially given how the `Sample` class is implemented and how limited `CombineWithContext` is.

Comment: If the sample rate configuration is small and provided during pipeline construction, then your sampling transform can hold it as a field and there's no need for side inputs. If the configuration is dynamically generated from data then you can design your join logic using `CoGroupByKey`; there are some examples here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#joins-with-cogroupbykey

Comment: I think side inputs and combine with context are the proper approach here. Are you having trouble defining what the accumulator state of the combine would be, or how to implement certain operations?

Comment: @jkff I am in fact having just that problem.  I'm using just a `MutableList` as the Accumulator, but having loads of issues from missing `Coder`s to other very fundamental issues.  Am I correct in assuming the Accumulator must be a subtype of some Accumulator supertype?

I briefly attempted to do this using two side inputs and a normal `DoFn` by using one side input as an incrementer  to keep track of how many items have been passed, however that didn't work due to side inputs being fundamentally immutable.

Comment: @jkff one big blocker is that, in trying to base this off of `Sample.java` in the Beam project, the `FixedSizedSampleFn` only has one `topCombineFn` and I'm struggling conceptually with how to specify multiple `topCombineFn` where their sizes are determined by a `PCollectionView` as those are only accessible within the `Context` provided in the functions of the class.

Comment: @jkff I may have solved my previous comment's problem. I'll update if I have figured it out. Thanks!